# UML class diagram: association between association class and another class

Tags: class, uml, associations, class-diagram

I have the classes `Specialisation` (Business Analyst, Project Manager, etc.), `Skills` (UML, BPMN, system analysis, scrum, etc). Between these two classes, I have an association class that divides skills on key/auxiliary skills for every specialisation and this assignment is like a predefined list. I have a question regarding the association between the association class and another class:

Let's say I want to select specialisations and skills for my project team A. For example, for team A, I need 2 x Business Analyst with key skills: BPMN and UML, a project manager with key skills: leadership, decision-making skill, and scrum skill, etc. So, I select only the necessary specialisations, the quantity of this specialisations and skills from the predefined lists.

I try to translate it into a class diagram, but frankly speaking, I don't know how to connect selected specialisations and skills in this case. I assume that my current version isn`t correct.

**Current version**
[image: current version]

I have tried the following two options, but I don`t think any is correct.

**Option 1**
[image: option 1]

**Option 2**
[image: option 2]

Comment: Why is Skill a Class and not an Enumeration?

Comment: It is a dictionary, smth like enumeration.

Comment: There’s lots to untangle here before you go nuts with 2nd order types. A `business analyst role` is a specialization of `role` and an instance of `role type`. An instance of `person` plays an instance of `business analyst role`.  `BPMN capability` is an instance of `capability type` that specializes `capability` and an instance of it inheres in an instance of `person`.

Comment: All the terms I mentioned that end in “type” are instances of `2nd order type`. All the other terms are instances of `1st order type`.

Answer (score 0):

#### What does the current model say?

It says that a `Team` (not Team A, which would be an instance of a team) is composed of several `TeamProfiles`, each associated with exactly one `Specialization`.

Each `TeamProfile` is also associated to one or more `TeamProfileSkill`. But nothing guarantees that the corresponding `Specialization` and `Skill` is the same than the specialization associated with the profile. In other words, it could be related to a profile skill of a completely unrelated profile.

#### What about the options?

The option 2 suffers of similar problems. You constrain (informally) to key skills, so you could associate the `TeamProfileSkill` only to a key skill of some specialization, but still, it could be of any (potentially unrelevant) specialization.

Option 1 is not better. The only difference is that you'd associate `TeamProfileSkills` directly to unrelated skills without the intermediary of the association class.

#### What do you really want?

It is not obvious for me to guess what you really try to achieve. Do you want that the `TeamPeofile` can be associated only to skills of the corresponding specialization? Is the `PfrofileSkill` representing all possible skills or all the required skills ? Can `TeamProfileSkill` contain more skills than the associated specialization? More information is necessary for providing more precise advice.

Whatever the intent, the key question is why you need the `TeamProfileSkill` ? Here some hints:

- Is it just to show the key skills of the team's specialization ?  In this cas you do not need it, and could use instead a **derived association with `Skill`**
- Is it to enrich generic information of the specialisation's skill with team specific attributes related to skills (e.g. experience level with the skill: 4 years)? In this case you could use a constraint that also cover the specialization.
- Is it to enrich the team's specialisation skills with additional skills? Solution depend on the semantics of the specilaization skills (i.e required, desired, possible)
- Is it independent skills and the goal is to match team's skills against profile requirements? In this case, you should not constraint the team's skill, as some matching algorithm has to find out what is relevant or not. This would be a specification of a behavior, not of a structural constraint.